# weird characters email in outlook mobile

Tags: html, email, encoding, character-encoding

Sending emails through ExactTarget I have a responsive design email template which looks good in IE, Firefox, Gmail Desktop, Gmail Android, and Outlook.  There are extra characters with accents in Outlook Mobile for Android only, I assume associated with a bad rendering of my UTF-8 encoding as Western 1252.

What can be done?

[image: extra characters]

Comment: This question is quite broad and very unclear. What software are you using to send emails?

Comment: Sorry, I am using ExactTarget to send these emails.

Comment: It seems to be happening at line breaks and feeds. Perhaps remove them from the email as they should not define the mark-up. Also, why not keep the UTF-8 encoding?

Comment: I didn't understand your comment "keep the UTF-8 encoding"